# Comparing two strings in XPath lexicographically

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an XML document with items `book` with attributes `.id`, for example .id `'bk100', 'bk102', 'bk105', 'bk112', 'bk130'`. I want to create an xpath that will return only those items which satisfy this condition:

```
.id > 'bk104'
```

That should return items with the .id `'bk105', 'bk112', 'bk130'`. I have this:

```
xpath("//book[@id>'bk112']");
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there any modifier to make this happen, or do I have to implement this manually?

Comment: "Lexicographic" ordering means one thing to mathematicians and something quite different to lexicographers. But I don't think the details of the exact order are what you are concerned about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [compare function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-compare) was added in XPath 2, which sadly isn't available.

With the [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you can [register PHP functions for use in XPath expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) and [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) does the trick there.

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<books>
    <book id="bk100"/>
    <book id="bk102"/>
    <book id="bk105"/>
    <book id="bk112"/>
    <book id="bk130"/>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions('strcmp');
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

foreach ($xpath->query("//book[php:functionString('strcmp', @id, 'bk104') > 0]") as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
<book id="bk105"/>
<book id="bk112"/>
<book id="bk130"/>
```

---

Otherwise you'll need to implement it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you you have constant id prefix

> bk

you can mitigate this problem by using standard xpath function *substring* (extract number from id) and *number* (convert string to number) as below:

```
xpath('//book[number(substring(@id, 3))>104]'))
```

Comment: Well, am I right to think that this wouldn't work lexicographically? If I have "bk104" > "xy104", the result is false, because lexicographically, "xy104" is greater than "bk104".

Comment: sure its numericaly solution - as i write above the condition is the same constant prefix (bk) for all ids (so the rest of id is number)

Comment: Right, of course. Well, that's unfortunately not the case. I guess I'll have to implement it manually. Thanks for your time. Upvote for creativity.